# postgres order chronologically by month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a master table which has the following info for some items

a timestamp called created_date - sample value -

```
2020-10-08 22:38
```

from this I extract the month and month name

```
EXTRACT(month from created_date) as month,
date_format(cast (created_date as timestamp), '%M') month_name,
```

I then do some other logic to find average values in a column

so my final query looks like this
with query as
(
SELECT
EXTRACT(month from created_date) as month,
date_format(cast (created_date as timestamp), '%M') month_name,
unit_price
FROM parent_table
WHERE
-- some criteria here
)

```
select month_name, month, avg(unit_price) as avg_unit_price from query 
group by month_name, month
```

The final output looks like the below table.

```
April 4 7.35    
December 12 43.79   
March 3 17.41   
October 10  50.15   
November 11 45.82   
September 9 58.64   
January 1   36.55   
February 2  25.07
```

Now I want to order this by date in chronological order, if I order by month then the order is not correct. I have tried to order with diff columns both month and month_name but it isn't correct.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this so the ordered data looks like this

```
September 9 58.64   
October 10  50.15   
November 11 45.82   
January 1   36.55   
February 2  25.07
March 3 17.41   
December 12 43.79
April 4 7.35
```

Comment: you will need to sort by a new column YYYYMM with numerical values. Use it for sort only. Hide it in the output

Comment: thanks Ahmad, that sees to do the job

Answer (score 1):

Dispense with the subquery . . . or include `created_date` in it.

Then you can use:

```
order by min(created_date)
```

Or, if it is an aggregation query, include `min(created_date)` in the subquery and use:

```
order by min(min_created_date)
```

However, I would advise that you include the year in the aggregation as well:

```
select year(created_date), 
       EXTRACT(month from created_date) as month,
       date_format(cast (created_date as timestamp), '%M') as month_name
       avg(unit_price) as avg_unit_price 
from query 
group by month_name, month, year
order by min(created_date);
```

Or, my preference is to just truncate the date:

```
select date_trunc('month', created_date) as yyyymm,
       avg(unit_price) as avg_unit_price
from . . .
group by yyyymm
order by min(created_date);
```